# Python check if a string is in dir() and if it is convert that string into a method/function call

Tags: python, function, methods

How do I turn a user generated string into a method or function call in Python2.7? Can you search the dir(object) to see if the method/function exists and then call that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to just try to call the method, if it's not there it will throw an exception, which you can handle.

```
>>> try: obj.a_method()
... except AttributeError: print 'No method a_method in this object'
... 
No method a_method in this object
>>>
```

Comment: This has served my specific problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
ui = input("Try something: ")
if ui in dir():
    func = eval(ui)
    func()
```

For example:

```
>>> def test():
    return "foo"

>>> if "test" in dir():
    func = eval("test")
    func()


'foo'
```

Comment: is the thought here that, since you are checking `dir` anyways so will only be executing objects that exist, `eval` is safe?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman something like that, yes, or certainly safer than `eval`ing any arbitrary string

Comment: What if the dir(object) call returns a list or tuple? I tried using your way with no luck. Is it because I am trying to do this with a Module object? Specifically I am trying to traverse an ast object step by step just to interact with my Abstract Syntax Tree.

Comment: @baallezx I think you need to revise your question with much more information about what you're doing and where exactly you're getting stuck (does "no luck" mean errors (provide traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?)

Answer (score 1):

Function names are just attributes, so you can do this:

```
try:
    getattr(object, methodname)()
except AttributeError as e:
    print 'Method %s not found or not callable!'%methodname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globals` it returns module's `__dict__`

```
def command_1():                                                                
    print "You are in command 1"                                                

def command_2():                                                                
    print "You are in command 2"                                                

def default():                                                                  
    print "Can't find your command"                                             

func = raw_input("ENTER YOUR COMMAND: ")                                        
your_func = globals().get(func, None)                                           
if your_func is None:                                                                                                                                       
    your_func = default                                                         

your_func()
```

#### Output:

```
ENTER YOUR COMMAND: command_1
You are in command 1
```

or

```
ENTER YOUR COMMAND: aaa
Can't find your command
```